# use keymap-set to bind to string

Tags: key-bindings

I used to use `global-set-key` to bind a key sequence to a string:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9> a") "text")
```

Now in v29.1, `C-h f global-set-key`:

> This is a legacy function; see `keymap-global-set` for the recommended function to use instead.

How to do what I described above using `keymap-global-set`?

---

```lisp
(keymap-global-set "<f9> b" "text")  ; => error, obviously

;; You may say I can use this:
(keymap-global-set "<f9> b" "t e x t")
;; No, I don't like it.

(keymap-lookup global-map "<f9> b")  ; => vector
;; How to make it return "text"?
```

Comment: Good question, +1. I think it might be a duplicate (please check by searching). Or maybe it was discussed in one of the mailing lists or bug list.

Comment: @Drew: I didn't find a similar question here (SE).  Maybe in the mailing list.

Comment: OK. Thanks for checking.

Comment: After some experimentation, I don't think there is a simple way to do that with `keymap-global-set`. But IMO, that is a feature, not a bug. So searching on the mailing list and asking the question there if it has not been answered already is probably the best way to proceed.

Comment: Maybe bug#61184?  (I haven't read them carefully yet.)

Comment: @NickD: "*But IMO, that is a feature, not a bug.*" -- Agree. I searched the documentation, found information that might be relevant, and wrote it down in my answer.

Comment: You can convert "text" to the internal representation using `key-parse`, but I'm not sure that's the official way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The string bound to a key sequence, e.g.,

```lisp
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c c") "\C-a\C-ptext")
```

is essentially a kind of keyboard macro, not a piece of text to be inserted.

For example,

```
first line
second line  <- type C-c c here
```

In [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual, 22.7.17 Putting Keyboard Events in Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs//manual/html_node/elisp/Strings-of-Events.html):

> However, **storing keyboard characters in a string is a complex matter**, for reasons of historical compatibility, and it is not always possible.

> We **recommend that new programs avoid dealing with these complexities** by not storing keyboard events in strings containing control characters or the like, but instead store them in the common Emacs format as understood by `key-valid-p`.

> However, most programs would do well to avoid these issues by **following the recommendations** at the beginning of this section.

So this may be an intended behavior.